# How to close an SSL connection in iOS using NSURLConnection

Tags: ios, ssl, nsurlconnection, ssl-certificate, nsmutableurlrequest

I have a certificate in my keychain, and there is an SSL connection created with that for one request. When we remove, that certificate from device keychain, how can I close that SSL connection. If any sample code is available, I appreciate if somebody can share that.

I need it as an urgent, please share some answers.